# Can't ping container from another container "bad address"

Tags: docker, docker-network

I've got stack with some containers. One of them can't be reached by others by his hostname and it's seems to be an ip address problem.

docker network inspect mystack

```
"Name": "mystack_default",
        "Id": "k9tanhwcyv42473ehsehqhqp7",
        "Created": "2019-08-22T16:10:45.097992076+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.2.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.2.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "5d8e4b8cba8889036a869a280d5996f104f250677b8c962dc45ba72441e1840d": {
                "Name": "mystack_api.1.t4oax9f5uyw0237h2ysgwrzxq",
                "EndpointID": "34037c244f828e035c54b5ef3f21f020cf046218b39ffc2835dd4156f3d2b688",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:23",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.35/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "49f6a8444475fdcea2f96bdb7fbc62b908b5cd83175c3068a675761e64500e0e": {
                "Name": "mystack_webview.1.biby87oba9z3awkb3n4439yho",
                "EndpointID": "d9c0551a0213e38651c352970d5970b3f80b067676b3fb959845e139b7261c1a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:20",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.32/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4099"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "mystack"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "1b4f79e8e881",
                "IP": "192.168.1.67"
            }
        ]
```

api service can ping webview service using hostname but it's not the good ip of my webview service :

```
# ping webview
PING webview (10.0.2.17) 56(84) bytes of data. // NOT THE GOOD IP ! (it should be 10.0.2.32)
64 bytes from 10.0.2.17 (10.0.2.17): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms 
64 bytes from 10.0.2.17 (10.0.2.17): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.099 ms
```

webview can't ping api service using hostname (bad address error) but it works with ip address of my service :

```
/app # ping 10.0.2.35
PING 10.0.2.35 (10.0.2.35): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.2.35: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.331 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.35: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.140 ms
^C
--- 10.0.2.35 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.140/0.235/0.331 ms
/app # ping api
ping: bad address 'api'
```

There is a problem with docker network but I don't know how to solve it. I already uninstall and reinstall docker, remove docker eth entries... Any idea ? Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I finally solved my problem but I don't really why. I removed all images, networks, launch with docker-compose, stop it, and relaunch it as a stack. Then I launch swarmpit after all.